# React stops rendering with child element

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to implement parent/child elements by hands, without copypasting from tutorials. Once I'm adding child element, React stops rendering, the page is blank:

```
var utmForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        Hello!
        <utmInput />
      </form>
    )
  }
});

var utmInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        Inputs
      </p>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(utmForm), document.getElementById('container'));
```

http://jsbin.com/katupa/edit?html,js,output

Can't guess yet why is that. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) doesn't complain about my code, also no errors in console.

Comment: I can see errors in your fiddle in console: `jsx processor compilation failed`, `Lower case component names (utmInput) are no longer supported in JSX`

Comment: Yes, exactly! But which console, actually? I don't see any errors in a browser with JSXTransformer.

Comment: @denis.peplin works fine https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/27405/

Comment: Dennis you know what the browser's console is right?

Comment: @DominicTobias the confusion probably lies in the fact that jsfiddle provides its own console, and that console doesn't show this error.

Comment: I found what was confusing: `Chrome` doesn't display this error, only `Firefox` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to console errors just change `utmForm` to `UtmForm`, `utmInput` to `UtmInput`

You can see browser console by pressing `ctrl + shift + i` and then click on console tab (in firefox and chrome).

Comment: Only `Firefox` displays this error, `Chrome` remains silent. I tried to disable `React` extension, no change. `Chrome` version is `47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)`.

Comment: @denis.peplin I can see this errors in both firefox and chrome. (chrome with  the same version)